# Ajax loading when reaching the bottom of container problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am building an image gallery (infinite scroll) and I am trying to "load more content" when I reach to the bottom of my container. (NOT bottom of page)

MY PROBLEM:
I load the page, everything is fine.  I reach to the bottom of my container, and the AJAX loads more data. Everything is fine here... but then my container should have more "height" since it has the new data.

But if I scroll just a little bit after that (NOT reaching the bottom of the NEW HEIGHT of the container), it loads the AJAX again right away... and it keeps loading as if it took the Height of the original container (without the new data).

I need it to RE-LOAD the AJAX once it reaches the bottom of the container (including the new loaded data each time).

MY JS CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var pageNumber = <? echo $page; ?>;
var perPage = <? echo $perpage; ?>;

var processing = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight() >=  $('#postswrapper').offset().top + $('#postswrapper').height() ) {

        if (processing == 1)
        return false;

        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();

        processing = 1;
        pageNumber++;   

        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "loadmore.php",
            method: "get",
            data: { page: pageNumber, perpage: perPage, search: "<?=$search?>", blogtag: "<?=$blogtag?>"},
            success: function(html)
                    {
                        if(html)
                        {
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                        }
                        else
                        { $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');  }
                    }
        }); // close AJAX

        processing = 0; 

    }  // close if($(window).scrollTop())
}); // close $(window).scroll

</script>
```

HTML OF MY CONTAINER:

```
<div style="display:flex; 
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
        justify-content: center; 
        align-content:  space-between;  
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 97%; " id="postswrapper">       </div>
```

Comment: Did you debug it checking for `$('#postswrapper').height()`? Is it your issue or no?

Comment: @A.Wolff if I add this:   `alert($('#postswrapper').height());`   after  if `($(window).scrollTop() +.`..   It keep alerting me with bigger and bigger height dimentions, but it also does it everytime I touch the scroll.  So no, the problem is not the wrapper height, it's the trigger

Comment: @A.Wolff It seems to be that the '>=' sign is alway '>=' so the code is executed every time I touch the scroll